# javascript/jquery remove relative path from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom

I'm using jquery to find and retrieve several img src's from the DOM, however the src's are in relative path format like this:

```
src="../../../../../dynamic/eshop/product_images/thumbnail_cache/366x366/042-1392_13760000.1.jpg"
```

I need to remove all the trailing slashes and append an absolute url. Is there anyway to achieve this without using regex in javascript or jquery?

Comment: you mean preceding slashes and dots?

Comment: Well a lot of people say regex is overkill for a lot of things, so I was wondering if there was another method. Regex is also welcome but I don't know the syntax very well

Comment: @Prisoner  yea that's what I mean

Comment: You want to change the `src` to a *different* URL, or to the *same* URL, but with an absolute path? Because the current absolute path should be available in the `this.src` property of the of the node (which is different to the relative path held in the `this.getAttribute('src')` property.

Comment: @DavidThomas I want the absolute path of the same URL. So... I should use `this.src` instead of `.attr('src')`?

Comment: I'd double-check with a `console.log(this.src);`, but I believe so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the URL

```
var url = '../../../../../dynamic/eshop/product_images/thumbnail_cache/366x366/042-1392_13760000.1.jpg';
```

Using regex

```
var fullurl = url.replace(/^.+\.\//,'');
```

Using index

```
var inx = url.lastIndexOf('./');
var fullurl2 = url.substring(inx+2, url.length)
```

Normal replace (if you're sure you only have `../`)

```
url.replace(/\.\.\//g, '');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rnY/1/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, does the regex method work with any length of preceding slashes and dots? I mean maybe some url's have shorter and some have longer slashes and dots

Comment: @user2028856 http://jsfiddle.net/a4rnY/2/ yes it does. Now that I think about it a normal replace should also work

Answer (score 0):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```
var segments = "/url/to/img".split('/');
alert(segments[segments.length-1]); // your value
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but could you please provide a small explanation how this works?

Comment: @user2028856, answer corrected see documentation. Function split your string by separator and create array of segments, to example code in answer return ['url','to', 'img'], your image name located in last segment.